# MVVM LIght impossible to bind one view on a TabItem

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, binding, mvvm-light, tabcontrol

I have spent more than 10 hours exploring most of what could find on the MVVM pattern and binding to a TabControl.

I prefer not giving my actual code, but my problem is slightly simple :

- I'm developing an application to Import/Export IDE (Informatica Data Exchange) Articles
- I've created a full DLL wich contains all Model Classes (it was a demand of the client to use that class in another app), that also contains an EF entity (in the form of a stored procedure, not tables)
- I'v got an IndexMainViewModel and associated view in the App.Ressources with a defined DataTemplate that binds the V and the VM, which will contains the 2 tabs.
- Each of those tabs has to display 2 different views : the ExportView which is related to my ExportViewModel, and the ImportView on the same buiding style.

For info : I've created a DLL that contains all my Models and WorkClasses (including my services and I also created a DAOlayout with interfaces there, all is great there)

I apologize if it does not look clear. If you need I'll put down my code.

Any simple Idea is most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Your problem isn't  clear. Do you face problem of loading UI after each tab click? @RizzCandy

Comment: In fact nothing is displayed : on the app start, my IndexMainView is Initialized with a TabControl in it. It's supposed to display my ExportView on the first tab, and my ImportView on the second tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up to the answer myself. I was confused about the view binding in the xaml code. I figured it out simply with this :

View :

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate >
        <!-- header template -->
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <!--content template-->
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:ExportView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

ViewModel :

```
 public sealed class IndexMainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private ObservableCollection<TabItem> _views;

    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Views
    {
        get { return _views; }
        set
        {
            _views = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Views);
        }
    }
    public IndexMainViewModel()
    {
        _views = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
        _views.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Export", Content = new ExportViewModel()});
        _views.Add(new TabItem { Header = "Import", Content = new ImportViewModel()});
    }
}
```

I also created a `TabItem` class with a `ViewModelBase` object (MVVM Light class object). This observable collection of views can be displayed if you don't miss the namespace `<views:ExportView/>` in the xaml code.

Answer (score 0):

In the design part i create two `Tab`, one is Upload and another is Download.

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem" x:Key="MainTabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                        <DockPanel Height="45" Width="245" >
                            <Separator Name="RightBorder" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" 
                                  Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
                            <Grid Cursor="Hand" Width="245" Background="Transparent" >
                                <TextBlock Name="TabItemTitle" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"

                            </Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                        </DockPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Name" Value="UploadTab">
                                <Setter TargetName="TabItemTitle" Property="Text" Value="Upload"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Name" Value="DownloadTab">
                                <Setter TargetName="TabItemTitle" Property="Text" Value="Download"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="White">
            <TabControl Name="MediaControl"   SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" Padding="0">
            <TabItem Name="UploadTab" Style="{StaticResource MainTabItem}">
                <Border Name="UploadTabPanel">
                    </Border>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Name="DownloadTab" Style="{StaticResource MainTabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="DownloadTabPanel">
                    </Border>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

After each `Tab` click `SelectionChanged event` will be fired and show your `UI` under the `TabItem` as child of a `Border`.In the `SelectionChanged event`, you have to add `UI` Part...

```
           private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    string tabItem = ((sender as TabControl).SelectedItem as TabItem).Name as string;
                    switch (tabItem)
                    {
                        case "UploadTab":
                            if (UploadInstance == null) 
                            {
                                UploadInstance = new UploadInstance();
                            }
                            UploadTabPanel.Child = UploadInstance;
                            break;
                        case "DownloadTab":
                            if (DownloadInstance == null)
                            {
                                DownloadInstance = new DownloadInstance();
                            }
                            DownloadTabPanel.Child = DownloadInstance;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex) { }
            }
```